# Disappearing Thumbnails with jquery Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, thumbnails

I'm working on a site that was picked up from another designer. I'm trying to "fix" the problems that were plaguing this site. Anyway, I'm having an issue with the thumbnails disappearing after the hover/zoom effect fires. This is happening mainly in Chrome. I have also run into an issue where the thumbnails are "smashed" after hover in Firefox. Here is the link to the site in progress: http://renovationcs.com.previewdns.com/ Here is a link to screenshot in Firefox: http://renovationcs.com.previewdns.com/problems/firefox-screenshot.jpg. They just disappear altogether in Chrome. There also appears to be a missing image graphic or something when initially hovered over.  I would really appreciate any help I can get. I'm just trying to poke my way through it and make it work. Thanks!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem i have seen so far is of height..

As I have checked in FF after hover the image, the thumb height decreases to 16px from 76px.

Try to fix the height using important in css. Also fix the height of  tag. That might solve the problem.. not sure..

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking a look.  I'll try your suggestions and see what happens.